# How to make drop-down in Ofbiz as read only?

Tags: xml, dropdown, ofbiz

I want to display the dropdown but make it read only with a default value. How can I achieve that? I am only new to Ofbiz. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. Pass in a list of values to the frontend and iterate through it, while checking a condition that will result to true if your default value is found.

```
<select id="OrderEntryKpiOptions_userLoginId" name="userLoginId">
    <#list usersList as user>
        <option value="${user.userLoginId}"  <#if requestParameters.userLoginId?if_exists == user.userLoginId> selected="true"</#if>>${user.personName}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```